# Recommend a UK based VPS host equivalent to Dreamhost

Tags: hosting, vps

I appreciate this question could be considered subjective and argumentative so can people make recommendations rather than arguing about the best. I believe the "correct" answer is the one closest to what I am looking for.

Basically I live in the UK but have been using the US based Dreamhost for about 6 years now, and my web projects are getting to the scale where the websites need to the UK based to cope with the demand and load.

I originally had shared hosting with Dreamhost but upgraded to a VPS a while ago, getting 512mb of RAM, unlimited disk space, bandwidth and domains for $30.

Their control panel is a custom *easy to use* build that they have created in house and offers features very similar to other web panels (as far as I am aware).

So basically my question boils down to, is there anywhere that offers an equivalent package? In all honesty as long as I have over 50gb HDD space and unlimited domains it doesn't really matter? Are there any VPS providers you would recommend as reliable?

I promise to check every link posted, many thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i can reccomend clustered.net or linode.com

vps.net is also good (shameless affilliate link http://www.vps.net/?r=lUOA)

i doubt you are going to get that pricing though
as a rough guide to get what you want on the above 3 mentions its going to cost (just for the vps no licenses)

clustered.net - £40 per month for there VPS70 package
linode.com $79.95 for Linode 2048
vps.net - £50 for 5 nodes

you have factor in licensing and other costs into this equation like IP's

my recomendations

- if you know you wont need outside UK in future, clustered.net
- good extra's like dns and level3 cdn, vps.net
- not fussed about fancy control panels or vps management,  linode.com

Answer (score 2):

webhostingtalk.com is probably the best place to research providers & pick-up good offers.  Though it does have a US slant, there are plenty of UK/EU offers too.